# PhpMyAdmin login screen

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, wamp

I didn't have this problem before but when I installed WAMP on a fresh copy of windows and when I wanted to open phpmyadmin, this screen appeared: [click me](http://shrani.si/f/b/hX/WyG9dHI/untitled.jpg)

Why? Why didn't I have this before? Is this new version or something? How can I login?

---

EDIT: Thanks for all the help and thanks for confirming this comes with the latest version! Though I do receive two messages on the bottom of the phpmyadmin screen now when I log in:

"Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'."

and "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."

Comment: You need to log in with your MySQL credentials.

Comment: I don't have any credentials because the installation of WAMP didn't ask me for any credentials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `WAMP` folder. And search `config.inc.php` file. When you open that file, the file will have something like this:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Search for this line:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

And change the ‘config’ into ‘cookie’:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Save that, then open up `phpmyadmin`, and it will work great.

**Answer for the updated question:**

Its just a warning to show that there is no password for the default user root. If you want to set password for root.

```
GO tp phpmyadmin interface->Previlages->select user root>edit Previlages->change password
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve those two messages also? (Edited the answer, look up)

Comment: You can also up-vote the solution. So that other user think its helpful and side by side I'll get reputation.

Comment: It may be obvious to some, but someone struggling with this problem might not realize at first that the code segments following the directions above: "Search for this line:" and  "And change the ‘config’ into ‘cookie’:" are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

it is added in new version of wamp server. Just type username as "root" and password as blank and click go.You can set password after login.

Comment: Thanks to both of you (Suresh and Mohit), thanks for confirming this comes with the latest version!

Though I do receive two messages on the bottom of the phpmyadmin screen: "Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'." and "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."